# java nio Files.find to count subdirectories

Tags: java, nio

I was expecting this code using Java 8's Files#find method from a `java.nio.File`  to return a count of all the sub directories of the current directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
    Files.find(Paths.get("."),
               Integer.MAX_VALUE,
               (path, basicFileAttributes) -> dirs.add(path.toFile()));
    System.out.println(dirs.size());
}
```

however, it always outputs 0. Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files.find` returns stream, which you haven't consumed hence the lambda you passed to add files to dirs not executed.
stream should be consumed, try the following

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      List<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
      Files.find(Paths.get("."),
             Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            (path, basicFileAttributes) -> 
      dirs.add(path.toFile())).forEach((ignore)->{});

     java.lang.System.out.println( dirs.size() );
}
```

Comment: this works, but I don't really understand why - I get that I'm not using the stream returned from `Files.find`, but I thought the `dirs.add` would get executed anyway?  what is the significance of `ignore`?

Comment: @Black there is no such significant meaning of ignore in java context, however in this context i used to name `ignore`, because we are not doing anything with the value, it will be your file path. Try replacing `(ignore)->{}` lambda with `System.out::println`

Comment: @Black put `sysout` statement in your lambda like `(path, basicFileAttributes) ->{ System.out.println("Exec lambda"); 
      return dirs.add(path.toFile()); } ).forEach((ignore)->{});` you can see if its executing or not, and when exactly its executing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs of [`Files#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-): the third param is a function used to decide whether a file should be included in the returned stream. You're not adding anything to the `dirs` list.

Try this where the matcher function filters for directories:

```
    List<Path> found = Files.find(start,
            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            (path, basicFileAttributes) -> path.toFile().isDirectory()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    java.lang.System.out.println(found.size());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `File.isDirectory()` to count them:

```
static int countSub(File[] directory) {
    int total = 0;
    for (File files : directory) {
        if (files.isDirectory()) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: not only does this not address the question itself; it wont even recurse

Comment: Fair enough. However, your problem was *count of all the subdirectories of the current directory* which this would solve.

Comment: @Black yes I read that. However, an alternative solution may have come in handy. That's all.